# Selenium not waiting for element to be visible causing error: invalid element state

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Error: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated.

So I have selenium requesting a page and then filling out a few input boxes then clicking a button to submit the form.

The issue I'm having is that selenium isn't waiting for the element to be visible so I have to manually place a time.sleep(2) to fix that but I would prefer to use a wait until they show up in case it takes longer or less time to load or if they don't load at all.

I have it setup like this currently to request the page, find the input field, check if the element exists and type the text into it, I get this error at the element.clear() part which doesn't happen when I include a time.sleep(2) after requesting the url:

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\example\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\example.py", line 125, in <module>
    completeForm(
  File "C:\Users\example\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\example.py", line 89, in completeForm
    typeText(Field, text)
  File "C:\Users\example\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\scratches\example.py", line 50, in typeText
    element.clear()
  File "C:\Users\example\Desktop\selenium-program\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 92, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\example\Desktop\selenium-program\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 693, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\example\Desktop\selenium-program\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 400, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\example\Desktop\selenium-program\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 236, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
```

Code

```
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import random
import time

#Setup selenium chrome browser with options

def setupBrowser():
    global driver

    options = {}

    chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
    driver = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)


#Type like a human
def typeText(element, text):
    success = False

    if doesElementExist(element):
        while success == False:
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(element)
            actions.click()

            element.clear()

            for character in text:
                actions.send_keys(character)
                actions.perform()
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.13, 0.4))

            if element.get_attribute("data-initial-value") == text:
                success = True


#check if element exists, times out after some time and returns error
def doesElementExist(element):

    timeout = 10
    try:
        element_present = EC.visibility_of_element_located(element)
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Error: Timed out after {} seconds waiting for element to load!".format(timeout))
        return False
    finally:
        return True


driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)

Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
text = "exampletexttowrite123"
typeText(Field, text)
```

Comment: Is URL public ?

Comment: Yes the whole program works when I place time.sleep(1) after driver.get(url) it's only when I remove the sleep it doesn't wait for the element to load. The url is a google form

Comment: See below, and it may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `typeText` needs corrections. It does not have `.perform()` so what happens is all the item will get stored in Actioncahins queue and the moment you write `.perform()` they will be release one by one.

**Code :**

```
def typeText(element, text):
    success = False

    if doesElementExist(element):
        while success == False:
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
            element.click()
            element.clear()
            

            for character in text:
                actions.send_keys(character).perform()
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.13, 0.4))

            if element.get_attribute("data-initial-value") == text:
                success = True
```

**PS :**

this method is directly accepting a `web element`, make sure the web element should be rendered properly.

**Update :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfMJRFOPF0qeJG3DHrbzbDR7nETPF0qE2D-r_F3kjjqdP9B1w/viewform")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Your answer']/preceding-sibling::input")))).perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Your answer']/preceding-sibling::input"))).send_keys('cruise')
```

Comment: I have actions.perform() just below the actions.send_keys(character) and that's working so far but I just changed it to what you suggested, do you know maybe why selenium isn't waiting for the element to load but returns True instantly?

Comment: See you are passing element here, `doesElementExist(element):` how did you get the element ? Was it properly rendered ?

Comment: I did try to change it from passing a web element to EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input') but it still shows the same error

Comment: This is the element Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')

Comment: Xpath looks brittle, can you show me some html, probably we can construct a relative xpath rather than having an absolute xpath.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfMJRFOPF0qeJG3DHrbzbDR7nETPF0qE2D-r_F3kjjqdP9B1w/viewform that's the xpath to the first field at the top, I'm hoping to reuse the doesElementExist() function in other parts I need to enter text so hopefully there is a way to wait for an element to load

Comment: replace this `//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input` with this `//div[text()='Your answer']/preceding-sibling::input`

Comment: also in place of `driver.find_element` use `WebDriverWait`

Comment: Okay replaced the xpath and that works but I still get the same error as the element is not loaded in time without the 1 second sleep Field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Your answer']/preceding-sibling::input")))

Comment: See above I have updated without `time.sleep(1)`

Comment: Awesome! This works, I will go ahead and use this in my code and mark this as answered

Comment: You will have to construct a good relative xpath for every web element. Good luck !